# displaying calendar items closest to today using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dictionary of my calendar items for a month (*date* as "key", *items* in the form of a list as "value") that I want to print out a certain way (That dictionary in included in the code, assigned to `dct`). I only want to display items that are **on** or **after** the current date (i.e. today). The display format is:

```
day: item1, item2
```

I also want those items to span only 5 lines of stdout with each line 49 characters wide (spaces included). This is necessary because the output will be displayed in conky (app for linux).

Since a day can have multiple agenda items, the output will have to be wrapped and printed out on more than one line. I want the code to account for that by selecting only those days whose items can fit in 5 or less lines instead of printing 5 days with associated items on >5 lines. For e.g.

```
day1: item1, item2
      item3
day2: item1
day3: item1,
      item2
```

Thats 3 days on/after current day printing on 5 lines with each line 49 char wide. Strings exceeding 49 char are wrapped on newline.

Here is the code i've written to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import heapq
import re
import textwrap

pattern_string = '(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i)(am|pm)'
pattern = re.compile(pattern_string)

# Explanation of pattern_string:
# ------------------------------
#(              #start of group #1
 #1[012]                #  start with 10, 11, 12
 #|             #  or
 #[1-9]             #  start with 1,2,...9
#)              #end of group #1
 #:             #   follow by a semi colon (:)
  #[0-5][0-9]           #     follw by 0..5 and 0..9, which means 00 to 59
            #(\\s)?     #       follow by a white space (optional)
                  #(?i)     #         next checking is case insensitive
                      #(am|pm)  #           follow by am or pm
# The 12-hour clock format is start from 0-12, then a semi colon (:) and follow by 00-59 , and end with am or pm.
# Time format that match:
# 1. "1:00am", "1:00 am","1:00 AM" ,
# 2. "1:00pm", "1:00 pm", "1:00 PM",
# 3. "12:50 pm"

d = date.today() # datetime.date(2013, 8, 11)
e = datetime.today() # datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 11, 5, 56, 28, 702926)
today = d.strftime('%a %b %d') # 'Sun Aug 11'

dct = {
'Thu Aug 01' : [' Weigh In'], 
'Thu Aug 08' : [' 8:00am', 'Serum uric acid test', '12:00pm', 'Make Cheesecake'], 
'Sun Aug 11' : [" Awais chotu's birthday", ' Car wash'], 
'Mon Aug 12' : ['10:00am', 'Start car for 10 minutes'], 
'Thu Aug 15' : [" Hooray! You're Facebook Free!", '10:00am', 'Start car for 10 minutes'], 
'Mon Aug 19' : ['10:00am', 'Start car for 10 minutes'], 
'Thu Aug 22' : ['10:00am', 'Start car for 10 minutes'], 
'Mon Aug 26' : ['10:00am', 'Start car for 10 minutes'], 
'Thu Aug 29' : ['10:00am', 'Start car for 10 minutes']
}

def join_time(lst):
    '''Searches for a time format string in supplied list and concatenates it + the event next to it as an single item
       to a list and returns that list'''
    mod_lst = []
    for number, item in enumerate(lst):
        if re.search(pattern, item):
            mod_lst.append(item + ' ' + lst[number+1]) # append the item (i.e time e.g '1:00am') and the item next to it (i.e. event)
            del lst[number+1]
        else:
            mod_lst.append(item)
    return mod_lst

def parse_date(datestring):
    return datetime.strptime(datestring + ' ' + str(date.today().year), "%a %b %d %Y") # returns a datetime obj for the time string; "Sun Aug 11" = datetime.datetime(1900, 8, 11, 0, 0)

deltas = [] # holds datetime.timedelta() objs; timedelta(days, seconds, microseconds)
val_len = []
key_len = {}

for key in dct:
    num = len(''.join(item for item in dct[key]))
    val_len.append(num) # calculate the combined len of all items in the 
                        # list which are the val of a key and add them to val_len
    if num > 37:
        key_len[key] = 2
    else:
        key_len[key] = 1

# val_len = [31, 9, 61, 31, 31, 49, 31, 32, 31]
# key_len = {'Sun Aug 11': 1, 'Mon Aug 12': 1, 'Thu Aug 01': 1, 'Thu Aug 15': 2, 'Thu Aug 22': 1, 'Mon Aug 19': 1, 'Thu Aug 08': 2, 'Mon Aug 26': 1, 'Thu Aug 29': 1}

counter = 0
for eachLen in val_len:
    if eachLen > 37:
        counter = counter + 2
    else:
        counter = counter + 1

# counter = 11

if counter > 5: # because we want only those 5 events in our conky output which are closest to today
    n = counter - 5 # n = 6, these no of event lines should be skipped

    for key in dct:
        deltas.append(e - parse_date(key)) # today - key date (e.g. 'Sun Aug 11') ---> datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 11, 5, 56, 28, 702926) - datetime.datetime(1900, 8, 11, 0, 0)

    # TODO: 'n' no of event lines should be skipped, NOT n no of days!  
    for key in sorted(dct, key=parse_date): # sorted() returns ['Thu Aug 01', 'Thu Aug 08', 'Sun Aug 11', 'Mon Aug 12', 'Thu Aug 15', 'Mon Aug 19', 'Thu Aug 22', 'Mon Aug 26', 'Thu Aug 29']
        tdelta = e - parse_date(key)
        if tdelta in heapq.nlargest(n, deltas): # heapq.nlargest(x, iterable[, key]); returns list of 'x' no. of largest items in iterable
            pass                                # In this case it should return a list of top 6 largest timedeltas; if the tdelta is in 
                                                # that list, it means its not amongst the 5 events we want to print
        else:
            if key == today:
                value = dct[key]
                val1 = '${color green}' + key + '$color: ' 
                mod_val = join_time(value) 
                val2 = textwrap.wrap(', '.join(item for item in mod_val), 37)
                print val1 + '${color 40E0D0}' + '$color\n          ${color 40E0D0}'.join(item for item in val2) + '$color'
            else:
                value = dct[key]
                mod_val = join_time(value)
                output = key + ': ' + ', '.join(item for item in mod_val)
                print '\n           '.join(textwrap.wrap(output, 49))

else:   
    for key in sorted(dct, key=parse_date):
        if key == today:
            value = dct[key]
            val1 = '${color green}' + key + '$color: ' 
            mod_val = join_time(value) 
            val2 = textwrap.wrap(', '.join(item for item in mod_val), 37)
            print val1 + '${color 40E0D0}' + '$color\n          ${color 40E0D0}'.join(item for item in val2) + '$color'
        else:
            value = dct[key]
            mod_val = join_time(value)
            output = key + ': ' + ', '.join(item for item in mod_val)
            print '\n           '.join(textwrap.wrap(output, 49))
```

The result is:

```
Thu Aug 22: 10:00am Start car for 10 minutes
Mon Aug 26: 10:00am Start car for 10 minutes
Thu Aug 29: 10:00am Start car for 10 minutes
```

I've commented the code heavily so it shouldn't be difficult to figure out how it works. I'm basically calculating the days farthest away from current day using datetime and skipping those days and their items. The code usually works well but once in a while it doesn't. In this case the output should have been:

```
Mon Aug 19: 10:00am Start car for 10 minutes
Thu Aug 22: 10:00am Start car for 10 minutes
Mon Aug 26: 10:00am Start car for 10 minutes
Thu Aug 29: 10:00am Start car for 10 minutes
```

since these are the days after the current day (Fri 16 Aug) whose items fit in 5 lines. *How do I fix it to skip `n` no of lines rather than no of days farthest away from today?*

I was thinking of using `key_len` dict to somehow filter the output further, by printing the items of only **those** days whose items length sum up to < or = 5...

I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to tell what you're asking here, and your code is a huge muddle.

However, the reason you're getting the wrong output in the given example is very obvious, and matches the `TODO` comment in your code, so I'm going to assume that's the only part you're asking about:

```
 # TODO: 'n' no of event lines should be skipped, NOT n no of days!
```

I don't understand why you want to skip to the *last* 5 lines after today instead of the first 5, but I'll assume you have some good reason for that.

The easiest way to solve this is to just do them in reverse, prepend the lines to a string instead of `print`ing them directly, stop when you've reached 5 lines, and then print the string. (This would also save the wasteful re-building of the heap over and over, etc.)

For example, something like this:

```
outlines = []
for key in sorted(dct, key=parse_date, reverse=True): # sorted() returns ['Thu Aug 01', 'Thu Aug 08', 'Sun Aug 11', 'Mon Aug 12', 'Thu Aug 15', 'Mon Aug 19', 'Thu Aug 22', 'Mon Aug 26', 'Thu Aug 29']
    if parse_date(key) < parse_date(today):
        break
    tdelta = e - parse_date(key)
    if key == today:
        value = dct[key]
        val1 = '${color green}' + key + '$color: ' 
        mod_val = join_time(value) 
        val2 = textwrap.wrap(', '.join(item for item in mod_val), 37)
        outstr = val1 + '${color 40E0D0}' + '$color\n          ${color 40E0D0}'.join(item for item in val2) + '$color'
        outlines[:0] = outstr.splitlines()
    else:
        value = dct[key]
        mod_val = join_time(value)
        output = key + ': ' + ', '.join(item for item in mod_val)
        outstr = '\n           '.join(textwrap.wrap(output, 49))
        outlines[:0] = outstr.splitlines()
    if len(outlines) >= 5:
        break
print '\n'.join(outlines)
```

There are a lot of ways you could simplify this. For example, instead of passing around string representations of dates and using `parse_date` all over the place, just pass around dates, and format them once at the end. Use string formatting instead of 120-character multiple-concatenation expressions. Build your data structures once and use them, instead of rebuilding them over and over where you need them. And so on. But this should be all you need to get it to work.

Comment: sorry , im a beginner. i seriously thought the fact i could write *most* of it was pretty cool :)

Comment: @koogee: It _is_ pretty cool. Everyone writes code that can be simplified or improved all the time. It's worth looking at your code to see if you can do that, trying to find multiple solutions to a problem and code them all, etc., not just trying to add on to what you have; that's how you keep learning (which doesn't stop when you become a professional; it stops when you retire…), and it's also how you keep your code maintainable so you can add new features.

Comment: thanks...ive improved the code based on your suggestions. however i like heapq better than using strings because that way the program is eliminating dates farthest away from today instead or just removing extra string for which you cannot set an intelligent criteria. With heapq the program knows its eliminating output based on the dates the output is associated with. I don't know if the end result makes much of a difference either way or how cpu intensive using heapq over and over again is but thats just the way my mind works.

Comment: @koogee: You're missing something important here: You've already sorted the strings in date order. So, you don't need to skip the ones that are too far ahead, you just need to stop as soon as you get too far ahead.